# How to merge only specific elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, concatenation

This is probably pretty straightforward but I'm really stuck: Let's say that I have a `vector=c("a", "b", "c","d","e")`. How can I concatenate only some specific elements? For example, how do I merge "b" and "c", which will lead me to the `vector=c("a","bc","d","e")` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
 i1 <- vector %in% c("b", "c")
 c(vector[!i1], paste(vector[i1], collapse=""))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, that's what I was looking for!